# What is the use of dispatchEvent() in WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I notice [WebSocket extends EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) and `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()` "[sends an Event to **the object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)". But it is not clear from that MDN document who the object is.

I had thought maybe that object was the receiver on the WebSocket server side and `dispatchEvent()` is another way to send a message to the ws server like `WebSocket.send()`

So I did the following test in the browser console to see **if that is the case**(using https://github.com/websockets/ws for ws server).

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

//instead of using ws.send('hello world'); I use dispatchEvent here
//as I want to know what dispatchEvent does, 
//e.g can it send my message to ws server like send() ?

ws.addEventListener('open', (evt) => {
      let event = new MessageEvent('message', {
          data: "hello world",
          lastEventId: '101'
       });
  ws.dispatchEvent(event);
});

ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});


//Here is my server codes
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3000 })
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log(`A ${ws.url}} connects`)
  ws.on('message', (evt) => {
     console.log(`on message:received: ${evt}`)
     ws.send('test callback')
  })
 })
```

But as it turns out the console immediately prints out "Message from server hello world" while ws server didn't get that event.

So what is the use of `dispatchEvent()` in WebSocket ?

Comment: `EventTarget.dispatchEvent() "sends an Event to the object". But it is not clear from that MDN document who the object is.` The object it refers to is the `EventTarget` object.

Comment: For my test, yes it is. So that is my question, what is the use of dispatchEvent() for WebSocket ?

Comment: There is no use. Its part of `EventTarget`. You can listen for events and dispatch events. Those are the two ends of a "pipe". WebSocket implements this class because it sends events and lets you listen for those events. It doesn't react to any events itself.

Answer (score 2):

The EventTarget interface is implemented by objects that can receive events, and is an interface that your `ws` (WebSocket) variable will implement to receive communication events from the low-level browser implementation of that network socket (such as when it successfully opens, and when a message is received).

However, you're not supposed to call it yourself. What you're doing is manually feeding it an event, and causing the WebSocket to behave as if it was an real event that has arrived from the remote server.

Therefore, your code is only useful in testing scenarios where you are emulating a server response.

Comment: "your code is only useful in testing scenarios where you are emulating server that isn't actually being connected to." That seems to be the case as my test shows. Thanks. But do you have more evidence for that ?

Comment: @Qiulang the easiest way to get evidence is to look at your remote server code, and ensure it is never sending the message 'hello world'. This will convince you that it's your code that is fooling the WebSocket into thinking it has received a remote message.

Comment: Which I already did! As I said I wrote the server code too with ws package. I am sure it didn't send that.

Comment: @Qiulang Just in case it isn't clear, your code is opening a websocket, and when it opens, immediately emulating an incoming message from the server. What you're doing is similar to injecting a simulated click event into an HTML element through code, and asking "but, how can you prove someone didn't click the mouse?" It should be enough that you were the one that emulated the event

Comment: That is not exactly correct "when it opens, immediately emulating an incoming message from the server.". When you do ws, you always need to `socket.addEventListener('message' ..` for 2 way communication. So it is NOT I "immediately emulating an incoming message from the server"

Comment: As I said in my code example I was not using  `ws.send('hello world'); ` but `ws.dispatchEvent(event);` to test if the server can get the message, which I didn't know the answer when I first tried it.

Comment: Your code listens for the 'open' event from your local websocket. This means that as soon as the websocket opens, the event fires and your event handler runs. And your event handler immediately then emulates an incoming MessageEvent

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you tried to get at. For a "normal" ws process, should not we listen to the open event to know ws connect is established? That is nothing special about my code except I test `dispatchEvent` to  see what I can get.

Comment: @Qiulang Your code listens for the open event, and then when the open event is received, your code immediately simulates an incoming message by calling dispatchEvent. Normal code would only ever listen for the open event in order to then actually send something to the server using ws.send() immediately after the socket opens. You should normally never use dispatchEvent.

Comment: I feel we are not on the same page. I know what is the "normal" process for ws. I changes `send()` to `dispatchEvent()` to test what `dispatchEvent()` can do. If it helps I would like to point out that this question is related to my other question (which has no answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72878023/how-do-i-set-messageevent-property-e-g-lasteventid-in-websocket-message

Comment: dispatchEvent is a function implemented by any object that wants to be notified of events. In the case of WebSocket, the function is only supposed to be invoked by the browser when communication events happen. But you're calling it yourself and pretending that events are happening. You're asking what it can do, and I've told you what it does and that you're not supposed to do anything with that function.